# Mapping a directory outside the web-app to URL in TOMCAT

Tags: image, jakarta-ee

I need to map an directory containing images which resides outside tomcat webapps folder, so that application can serve those images.

I am making a J2EE Web application running under tomcat 6. User can upload/delete images in the application. Currenly I store these images to a directory under application's WebContent folder, but I want to take it outside the tomcat (e.g. C:/test/images).

I need to know how to I configure tomcat so that if I access URL http://.com/images/abc.jpg , it serves the image from directory C:/test/images

Thanks,

Answer (score 35):

Add a <Context> tag in server.xml, inside the <Host> tag:

```
<Context path="/images" docBase="C:/test/images/" />
```

Docs will be accessible at `http://localhost:8080/images`

Comment: This is not worked... Can you please be more specific?? I can not access via this trick. I am using Liferay

Comment: I don't know liferay. Is it based on tomcat?

Comment: Yes, it is based on Tomcat. I am using Liferay 6.2.0 m2 version which used tomcat 7. As per  my knowledge this is the same normal tomcat related scenario. Help me please

Comment: I follow the same. But at the calling time like http://localhost:8080/images............ It will give Error 404 The requested resource (/images/) is not available. Is it liferay issuue???

Comment: OK, I've also tested on liferay 6.1.1: it works like a charm; however, you need to specify the file you want to display, not the directory.

Comment: It works for accessing, but i need upload too. Is that work for upload? I tried in my php script, got path error.

Comment: @Lars well the question is about tomcat, not php. Are you using both tomcat and apache?

Comment: @MauricePerry Nope, just tomcat.

Comment: @Lars then you must write an upload servlet in java to deal with uploads

Comment: This works but how can i provide security for accessing resource

Comment: @MauricePerry can you please provide more details, i am just having context tag with doc base pointed to external location. any reference link pls.

Comment: When I use absolute path (path="d:/Programs/Tomcat/webapps/images/"), it show error: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property  
  
Then I change to use relate path (path="../images/"), it works !  
  
Hope my experience will help

Answer (score 5):

in Tomcat8 you can also add PotsResources to you META-INF/context.xml as follow :

```
<Context>
    <Resources allowLinking="false">
        <PostResources readOnly="false"
                       className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                       base="path-to-your-local-folder"
                       webAppMount="/images"/>
    </Resources>

    ...
</Context>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but found a solution.

If you are using Eclipse and a Tomcat plugin then please note that the Eclipse Tomcat plugin creates a separate `CATALINA_BASE` under the Eclipse `workspace` directory.

You can go to this location and you will find `server.xml`.
Use *that* `server.xml` and it will work.

My actual tomcat directory is:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.62x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\conf
```

and my Eclipse Tomcat server uses:

```
C:\workspace\JSF\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf
```

Use the workspace path and `server.xml` from this location.

Add this in `server.xml` inside the host tag:

```
< Context docBase="D:/personal"  path="/images" />
```

and it will work if `D:/personal` has `1.png`, and then the url `http://localhost:8080/images/1.png` will load the image.

Comment: How can the servlets and jsp file will be accessed. This is changing the default context

Comment: This works but how can i provide security for accessing resource

Comment: Perfecto.................... however in my case the path was temp1 insted of temp0

Comment: Thank you. you saved my lots of time