# Change docBase for apache tomcat in Netbeans

Tags: apache, netbeans, configuration, docbase

I have tried changing the docBase (with the help of several tutorials for serving static images from outside WebApp)of the Apache Tomcat installed by Netbeans, but till now no luck for me and **getting 404 error**.

```
<Context path="/WebApp/images" docBase="C:\\Users\Digvijay\Pictures\SAB" />
```

I am using windows.

I am not sure if there is some other way to configure Apache Tomcat installed by netbeans.

By the way below are the links for the solutions I tried

[Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)

[Mapping a directory outside the web-app to URL in TOMCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552812/mapping-a-directory-outside-the-web-app-to-url-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps works for me (NetBeans 7.3) ...

1. Select "Services" tab in NetBeans (top-lefthand box)
2. Right-click "Servers :: Apache Tomcat " and select "Edit server.xml" item
3. Put  content as described in links and save file
4. Right-click "Servers :: Apache Tomcat " and select "Restart"