# Tomcat 8 - Include external files

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm running Tomcat 8 on Linux and there I have a folder

```
/opt/files
```

where tomcat and other applications should save and access files. 
However, I don't know how to set this up in Tomcat to make use of these files

Comment: i didn't get you?

Comment: On Linux there is this "/opt/files" folder which is outside of the Tomcat folder. Tomcat folder is located at the documents folder in my mac. In this /opt/files folder there are images I want to display in my tomcat app, but that doesn't work with an absolute path in the image tag. So I somehow have to include this /opt/files in my tomcat app

Comment: What files did you want *Tomcat* itself (the container itself, not an webapp installed in Tomcat) to store there? If log files, then you configure location in the logging configuration file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean tomcat itself, I mean tomcat apps as well as some other applications

Comment: have you tried with Adding a `<Context>` tag in `server.xml`, inside the `<Host>` tag:` in tomcat refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552812/mapping-a-directory-outside-the-web-app-to-url-in-tomcat) for more details.

Comment: So, it sounds like you want a webapp (not Tomcat) to serve up static files that are not actually packaged with the webapp? Did I understand that right? If so, unpackage the .war file and create symbolic links as necessary.

Comment: Yes! That's what I want to do! @RajithPemabandu  no I haven't. How do I do this?

Comment: @RajithPemabandu Tomcat discourages the use of `<Context>` in `server.xml`. You should instead create context XML files in the `.../conf/Catalina/localhost` folder. Quoting [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context): *It is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file.*

Comment: @Andreas suppose you are correct. this may be a solution. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143697/adding-external-resources-to-class-path-in-tomcat-8)

Answer (score -1):

**A**. Use linux soft link is the easiest way

```
sudo ln -s /opt/files /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/optfiles
```

You don't needed change any thing about tomcat.

**B**. You can also make a soft link to your `webapps` fold, or even in your `webapps/myapp` folder (use `sudo ln -s /opt/files /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/myapp/optfiles` ), but in this situation you must change `context.xml` file

```
 <Context allowLinking="true" >
```

the `allowLinking` link attributes make the files accessible, but not recommend for safety reason.

and

**C**. Depends how you install the tomcat 8, in short, find your tomcat `conf` direcotry, change the server.xml like below

```
   <Server ...>

    <Engine>
       ...
      <Service>
     ...
           <Host name="image.hostname.com"  appBase="/opt/files"
                unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
                xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
          </Host>
          <Host name="app.hostname.com"  appBase=""
                unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
                xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
          </Host>

       </Engine>
      </Service>
    </Server>
```

and now your can access your file through `http://your.hostname.com:8080`

If you use `ubuntu` `apt-get` install your tomcat, you can find the configuration files holds in folder `/var/lib/tomcat8/conf` or `/etc/tomcat8/`

Comment: According to [comment by OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350445/tomcat-8-include-external-files#comment73764045_43350445), the `/opt/files` folder only stores some images that webapp needs. Your solution here moves the entire webapp to the folder. That is not what was requested.