# Image not showing in JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I do have simple JSP web page, but it's not displaying an image

This is my JSP page where it will fetch the image from pics folder under web content

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>

     <img width = "80" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pics/">
  </body>
</html>
```

But the page looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should somewhat be like

```
<img width = "80%" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pics/imagename.jpg">
```

File name is necessary and change 80 to 80% because your image might be too big and might just display a part of it

Also make sure

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

is not empty

And to be absolutely sure

```
<img width = "80%" src="check_with_original_directory/pics/imagename.jpg">
```

Comment: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` , how to check this path is empty or not

Comment: Just print it on your screen to verify at first

Comment: its printing /gallerywar

Comment: If it's the directory you're looking for, then well and good!

Comment: gallery war is my project name and main directory

Comment: Yeah, that's the correct directory, hope you have your images at "gallery war/pics/"

Comment: there is four pics  and is there anything i am missing

Comment: First try to display one of your images using `<img width = "80%" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pics/kids.jpeg">`

Comment: 80% means it'll cover 80% width of your screen, to include all 4 you're going to have to adjust the width as applicable

Comment: single image is displaying now, how to display all the four images at a time

Answer (score 0):

First Try an output with ${pageContext.request.contextPath}: make sure its where you expect the /pics/ folder to be

Next de path should mapped correctly: for example in de context.xml in tomcat

```
<Context path="/media/pics" docBase="C:/data/pics" debug="0" privileged="true">
</Context>
```

Extra tip:
Have a look at
[Mapping a directory outside the web-app to URL in TOMCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552812/mapping-a-directory-outside-the-web-app-to-url-in-tomcat)

Always have your media files separated outside your tomcat folder